# Visual Studio 2015 - Save Window Layout - not working

Tags: layout, visual-studio-2015

I recently installed Visual Studio 2015 (Pro, Update 1) and was eager to start using the new "Save Window Layout" feature.  However, it seems to not work on my system.

No matter how many times I use the "Save Window Layout" feature, when I return to the "Apply Window Layout" menu, I only see "No Saved Layouts".

I don't get any errors during the save (though, no confirmation either). Starting VS with the "/log" switch doesn't reveal anything of interest.

I do not have any other layout manager installed in VS2015 and I've also done a "Reset Window Layout" a few times hoping to kickstart the thing, but that hasn't helped either.

I'd appreciate thoughts on what might be wrong or how I can further debug this.

*** UPDATE ***

I just tried to export my current VS2015 settings via the "Import and Export Wizard".  At the end of the process, I get this info:

> Your settings were exported, but there were some errors.
>
> Error 1:  Failed to export settings for '#2015' [code 7369]
>
> Error 2:  Failed to export settings for 'Window Layouts' [code 7658]

I assume that's likely caused by the same underlying issue.  Does that shed any new light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by:

- Exporting all current settings (Tools | Import and Export Settings...)

(as mentioned above, this failed to export "Window Layouts")

- Reset all settings (Tools | Import and Export Settings...)
- Reimport my previously exported settings (Tools | Import and Export Settings...)

After that, I seem to have all of my original settings back and I can now save window layouts as expected.

Comment: I have the same problem but I can't resolve it using the reset feature.
As soon as I change something in the UI, the export fails with "Failed to export settings for '#2015' [code 7369]" :(

Comment: This also did not work for me.  I am also unable to change the color theme - it keeps switching back to "blue".

Comment: This feature simply does not work. Not sure why the Visual Studio team brag about it in their presentations.